# Input using useRef changing its value without updating its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

Hey guys, thanks in advance

I have the following problem, using an input component and taking its value by useRef due to the component's renderings, I was wondering if I could add a mask function and edit this value inside the input without having to render it to each character typed. for performance.or would anyone have any tips on how to do?

example of the code used:

`index.js`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import InputIcon from './inputIcon';
export default function Login() {
 const [userState, setUserState] = useState('');
 return (
  <InputIcon
   inputRef={inputUserRef}
   functionUpdatedValueRef={text => functionUpdateValueInputUser(text)}
  />
 )

}
```

`inputIcon.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
export default function InputIcon({
  inputRef,
  functionUpdatedValueRef,
}){
 return (
  <InputIcon
   ref={inputRef}
   onChange={() => functionUpdatedValueRef(inputRef.current.value)}
  />  
 )
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a react mask library? like for example: https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask

Comment: @MohamedMagdy, it's a good idea, I'll use it while I want to create the functions myself. Thx.